# Order view in Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2.2

**Error:**

**Order View** 
Information Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved. This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Looks like error in the code. Check this: http://bka.github.io/magento2/2015/12/28/widget-store-properties-changed.html Also do google search, you will find similar posts with solution.